# Conforming to NSCoding

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting the error that this class does not conform to NSCoding protocols.  Maybe another set of eyes would help.  I have tried to add comments to make it clear what each func is doing.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Search: NSObject, NSCoding {

// Global Variables
var articlePicture: UIImage!
var articleTitle: String

// MARK: Public Init
init(articlePicture: UIImage, articleTitle: String) {
    self.articlePicture = articlePicture
    self.articleTitle = articleTitle
}

// Required NSCoding Protocol
required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let articlePicture = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "articlePicture") as? UIImage,
        let articleTitle = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "articleTitle") as? String
        else { return nil }

    self.init(
        articlePicture: articlePicture,
        articleTitle: articleTitle
    )
}

// Required NSCoding Protocal
func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(self.articlePicture, forKey: "articlePicture")
    coder.encode(self.articleTitle, forKey: "articleTitle")
}

// Initialize [Search]
static var searches = [Search]()

static func getSearches() -> [Search]{
    return searches
}

static func setSearch(search: Search){
    searches.append(search)
}

// NSUserDefaults Searches Array funcs
static func saveSearches(){
    let searchData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: searches)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(searchData, forKey: "searches")
}

static func loadSearches() -> [Search]{
    let searchData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "searches") as? NSData

    if let searchData = searchData {
        searches = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: searchData as Data) as? [Search])!
        return searches
    }
    return searches
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tips: press `Cmd + 4` to open the Issue Navigator and Xcode will tell you more details.

In Swift 3, the encoding function has changed:

```
func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    // Swift 2 and older
}

func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
    // Swift 3
}
```

Change the method's signature and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 there is another way to encode/decode classes. Now you'll only have to conform to the protocol `Codable`. No more need to write all your encode and decodes and it supports classes without NSObject & enums & structs.

```
final class Search: Codable {

}
```

For more information, read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable

Comment: This is not true. NSCoding totally does not go away. You still need it. You have not answered the question at all.

Comment: You don't need NSCoding anymore to decode/encode in Swift 4. If you read the more information link you'll understand. It is indeed not the answer to the question, I've provided another way to decode/encode that's more up-to-date.

Comment: Your very first sentence is wrong. NSCoding has not changed completely. It hasn't changed at all. And you will still meet with a need to implement `encode(with)` and you are not explaining what to do. Finally, your answer is irrelevant to what was asked. And it's link-only. It's a wrong unhelpful answer.

Comment: I think you don't understand. Codable is Swift 4 way to decode/encode classes/structs/enums. You can still use NSCoding, but those only work on classes with NSObject. If you use Codable, you don't need to implement `encode(with: )`, it's optional.

Comment: That's true, but it isn't what you said in your answer.